# Runnning NetLogo Mode from Python Throws RuntimeException

Tags: python, netlogo, pynetlogo

I am trying to connect NetLogo from Python. I am following the official pyNetLogo documentation. Here is my code.

```
import pynetlogo

netlogo = pynetlogo.NetLogoLink(
    gui=True,
    netlogo_home="/home/protik/NetLogo/"
)

netlogo.load_model("../Netlogo-model/ICS1023.nlogo")
netlogo.command("setup")
```

It starts the NetLogo interface but fails to run the NetLogo model. It throws this following error.

```
Exception                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
 File NetLogoLink.java:121, in netLogoLink.NetLogoLink.loadModel()
 
Exception: Java Exception
 
 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 
 java.lang.RuntimeException
Traceback (most recent call last)
 File ~/anaconda3/envs/netlogo-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynetlogo/core.py:246,
   in NetLogoLink.load_model(self, path)
      245 try:
  --> 246     self.link.loadModel(path)
      247 except jpype.JException as ex:
 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
NetLogoException                          
  Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[1], line 8
       1 import pynetlogo
       3 netlogo = pynetlogo.NetLogoLink(
       4     gui=True,
       5     netlogo_home="/home/protik/NetLogo/"
       6 )
 ----> 8 netlogo.load_model("../Netlogo-model/ICS1023.nlogo")
       9 netlogo.command("setup")
 
 File ~/anaconda3/envs/netlogo-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynetlogo/core.py:249,
 in NetLogoLink.load_model(self, path)
     247 except jpype.JException as ex:
     248     print(ex.stacktrace())
 --> 249     raise NetLogoException(str(ex))
 
 NetLogoException: java.lang.RuntimeException
```

On the NetLogo interface a dialogue box pops up and shows the following line.

```
error in loading model java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception
```

By the way, the netlogo model itself runs fine. It only creates error while running from Python. I have checked jvm_path which seems to be correct.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so
```

What could be the solution?

Comment: What version of pynetlogo do you have?  Take a look at https://github.com/quaquel/pyNetLogo/issues/23

Comment: pynetlogo Version 0.5.1